# Beamer: How to remove shadows under header

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I would like to remove the shadow (gradient fading) under the header.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}      
\begin{frame}{Frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx. Did you see the following question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/beamer-how-to-remove-shadow-under-the-title-on-a-given-frame?

Comment: I did see it, but since I wanted to remove the shadows globally and from the header I didn't understand how to adapt solution to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]` to the preamble. See below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=false,shadow=false]
\begin{document}
\title{Testing}
\author{myself}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction}      
\begin{frame}{Frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```